# How to control the FirebaseMessagingService when the switch is off?

Tags: android, firebase, sharedpreferences

I use FirebaseMessagingService and SharedPreferences.

I try to get Notification Message using Firebase when switch is checked.

So I made the code like this.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Switch toggleSwitch;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        toggleSwitch = findViewById(R.id.toggleSwitch);

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("state", MODE_PRIVATE);

        toggleSwitch.setChecked(sharedPreferences.getBoolean("state", true));
        toggleSwitch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (toggleSwitch.isChecked()) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Switch On", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("state", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                    editor.putBoolean("state", true);
                    editor.apply();
                    toggleSwitch.setChecked(true);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Switch Off", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("state", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                    editor.putBoolean("state", false);
                    editor.apply();
                    toggleSwitch.setChecked(false);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(@NonNull RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("state", MODE_PRIVATE);
        if (sharedPreferences.getBoolean("state", true)) {
            if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
                sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle(), remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
            }
        }
    }

    private void sendNotification(String messageTitle, String messageBody) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        String channelId = getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id);
        Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle(messageTitle)
                .setContentText(messageBody)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            String channelName = getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_name);
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId, channelName, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }

        notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

This code works normally when the app is running.

However, when you shut down the app, Notification Message comes even when the switch is off.

Can't FirebaseMessagingService be controlled by SharedPreferences?

Or did I do something wrong?

Plz help me.

Answer (score 0):

You have two types of notifications - "data" and "notification". If you go into this webpage: [Handling Received Messages](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive?hl=en#handling_messages) You will see that depending on your actual payload received in the notification, you can control the notification.

What I would try is I would try to send only "data" payload in notification, and then check how the FirebaseMessagingService works for different scenarios: when app is in tray, when app is totally killed etc.

I expect that on certain devices (mainly from Chinese manufacturers), when the app is killed and not whitelisted, you won't receive callback in `onMessageReceived` and you won't be able to control the notification.